# MVC 5 Scaffolding Code generation with an Inherited Entity causes System.Core already imported

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used **Entity Framework DB First** approach to create my model. I spent many hours fighting with the EDMX to set up the inheritance correctly (0 errors). Then now when **trying to create either an MVC 5 Controller w/ Views using EF, or add a View for the inheriting class** I revieve this error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>
> 'There was an error in compilation of the type
>   'CostaPropertyServices.Models.PropertyInfoEntities'.
>
> CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'System.Core,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has
>   already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.'

I have two classes: Person and Vendor.
Vendors inherit from Persons, and add only an int ID field named PackageID.

[image: EDMX Graphical representation of Person and Vendor entities]

If anyone has any idea why I would really appreciate it. EF Inheritance seems to have been much more trouble than it's worth so far. Many Thanks.

Edit: Maybe I'm not supposed to be generating the views for inheriting entities? Or maybe I've not configured the inheritance correctly (Not set base to abstract?)

---

**Person.cs**

```
namespace CostaPropertyServices.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Created { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modified { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Deleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Vendor.cs**

```
namespace CostaPropertyServices.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Vendor : Person
    {
        public int PackageID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case the problem was that in solution I was referencing project that was compiling with .NET Framework 3.5. As soon as I've switched the project compilation to .NET Framework 4.5 everything started working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution! Well, to let me add controllers and views for the entity at least. I'll describe it briefly for anyone who is stuck on this too, however I plan to come back and expand this answer as soon as time allows.

It so happens that scaffolding worked completely fine with non-inheriting entities, and my project didn't seem to contain any references to System.Core, let alone a duplicate one. This made me think it was a compatibility issue with inheritance and the default scaffold-er.

**Steps to Fix:**

1. Install MVCScaffolding using NuGet.

   ```
   PM> Install-Package MvcScaffolding
   ```
2. Run the following command via Package Manager Console

   ```
   PM> Scaffold Controller Vendor -Repository
   ```

   ***Edit***: Pass `-DbContextType [YourProjectEntities]` *to specify a DbContext to update rather than it creating a new one you probably don't want.*
3. Update methods in generated VendorRepository.cs to use Persons table and not (non-existant) Vendors table. Below was my result:

   ```
   public class VendorRepository : IVendorRepository
   {
       PropertyInfoEntities context = new PropertyInfoEntities();

       public IQueryable<Vendor> All
       {
           get { return context.Persons.OfType<Vendor>(); }
       }

       public IQueryable<Vendor> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Vendor, object>>[] includeProperties)
       {
           IQueryable<Vendor> query = context.Persons.OfType<Vendor>();
           foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {
               query = query.Include(includeProperty);
           }
           return query;
       }

       public Vendor Find(int id)
       {
           return context.Persons.OfType<Vendor>().SingleOrDefault(v => v.PersonID == id);
       }

       public void InsertOrUpdate(Vendor vendor)
       {
           if (vendor.PersonID == default(int)) {
               // New entity
               context.Persons.Add(vendor);
           } else {
               // Existing entity
               context.Entry(vendor).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
           }
       }

       public void Delete(int id)
       {
           var vendor = context.Persons.OfType<Vendor>().SingleOrDefault(v => v.PersonID == id);
           context.Persons.Remove(vendor);
       }

       public void Save()
       {
           context.SaveChanges();
       }

       public void Dispose() 
       {
           context.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Eureka!

NOTE: See [this blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/) for standard usage, tips and customisation.

Comment: Your solution doesn't really work in my scenario: VS2012, MVC4 project, EF 5.0. I create the model first and follow this tutorial to add a "Discriminator" in my Person table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx I use the MvcScaffolding you suggested... it creates all views etc but it creates a new context and when I save something, it saves it in a new database. If I modify the context to be a partial class and be the same as the already existing context, I get the error "Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required."

Comment: @firepol When using DB First, you need to pass '-DbContextType PropertyInfoEntities' as well to tell it to use your original model and not create a new one. This tool may have been designed with Code First in mind, however it's extremely powerful and I am using it to pre- and re-generate templates for all my entities.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I did as you suggested and left away "Repository" (I don't need any repository). It worked like a charm except I have all my tables and controller "singular" but the tool pluralized e.g. controller, views "Students" instead of "Student"... I researched a bit and found out that this can be fixed by using this command: Scaffold Controller StudentController -DbContextType MyEntities (Changed in the initial command: "Controller StudentController", instead of "Controller Student", in my case)